# dependent dropdown is not showing dropdown list data

Tags: php, ajax, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create dependent dropdown where a person can select a particular shop depending on a region like south, north, east, west.
I have created a database where 4 columns are present like id,region_id, region, store name. I have 2 dropdowns one shows the region and another shows store name. Both are called from the database. Region dropdown is showing all regions.but store name is blank. 
I am trying to fetch stores by region id. if region_id==' ' then it will call select query where region_id gets a match. I need help if I am doing anything wrong. That's why I am not getting the results.

Code:
dashboard.php

```
<tr>
    <th>
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-md-5 control-label">Date</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="date" class="form-control  c-square c-border-2px c-theme" id="inputEmail3-55" placeholder="" name="date"> 
        </div>
    </th>
    <th> 
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-md-3 control-label">Region</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <select class="form-control  c-square c-border-2px c-theme" name="region" id="region">
                <?php 
                    $sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT DISTINCT region FROM store_details");
                    while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
                    echo "<option value=\"owner1\">" . $row['region'] . "</option>";
                    }
                ?>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </th>
    <?php $region_id =(isset($_POST['region_id']));{
            echo $region_id;
    }?>
    <th>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-md-6 control-label">Store Name</label>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <select class="form-control  c-square c-border-2px c-theme" name="store_details" id="states-list">
                    <option value=''>Select Store</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
        </div>
    </th>
</tr>
```

SerachRegion.php

```
<?php
    require_once('DbConnection.php');
    if(isset($_POST['region_id'])){
    $region_id =$_POST['region_id'];
}
    if($region_id!=''){
        $states_result = $conn->query('select * from store_details where region_id='.$region_id.'');
        $options = "<option value=''>Select store</option>";
        while($row = $states_result->fetch_assoc()){
            $options .= "<option value='".$row['region_id']."'>".$row['name']."</option>";
        }
        echo $options;
        }
?>
```

Ajax Code:

```
<script>
$('#region').on('change', function(){
var region_id = $(this).val();
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "SearchRegion.php",
data:{region_id:region_id},
success: function(result){
$("#states-list").html(result);
}
});
});

</script>
```

I have checked DbConnection.php file it is working fine. Just the issue is this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TdZ3.png)

Store Name dropdown is blank. and i am not getting any errors.

Comment: You have `$('#region').on('change', function(){`, but I don't see an `id="region"`, only a `name="region"`

Comment: region is the id of first region dropdown

Comment: have you checked your browser console to see if your ajax has fired?

Answer (score 1):

In your PHP function, you check the isset of post value. If you check the isset it returns true or false only for that variable.

For Example:

```
$expected_array_got_string = 'somestring';
var_dump(isset($expected_array_got_string['some_key']));
```

Output Will be:

```
bool(true)
```

So You need to change your variable declaration like:

```
    if(isset($_POST['region_id'])){
       $region_id =$_POST['region_id'];
    }
```

In your Ajax you need to get this type of value:

```
$('#region').on('change', function(){
        var region_id = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "SearchRegion.php",
          data:{region_id:region_id},
          success: function(result){
            $("#states-list").html(result);
        }
        });
    });
```

**EDITED:**

This is tested from my end: sample code is

> test1.php

```
<html>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
</html> 
<select id="_city">
    <option value="1">
        ONE
    </option>
    <option value="2">
        TWO
    </option>
    <option value="3">
        THREE
    </option>
</select>

<select name="store_details" id="states-list">
    <option value=''>Select Store</option>
</select>
<script>    
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#_city').on('change', function(){
          var region_id = this.value;
          $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "change.php",
          data:{region_id : region_id},
          success: function(result){
                $("#states-list").html(result);
            }
        });
    });
 });
</script>
```

> change.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['region_id'])){
       $region_id =$_POST['region_id'];
       echo '<option value="'.$region_id.'">'.$region_id.'</option>' ;

       exit;
    }
?>
```

Try this for ajax call

Comment: No Luck. Is there anything else that i have missed. I really stuck

Comment: What is your Post value in SearchRegion.php? print the post value in SearchRegion.php file

Comment: Again No luck. :(.Dropdown is blank

Comment: I am getting error: "Undefined variable: isset and Fatal error: Function name must be a string in"  For this :if($isset($_POST)){
       $region_id =$_POST['region_id'];
    
    }

Comment: Try with this variable declaration in ajax: `var region_id = $('#region').find(":selected").text();`

Comment: its if(isset) only. $ typed mistakenly

Comment: Did you change your ajax code to mine? bcoz your data is not goes post value

Comment: I have updated my answer with your ajax code. Now you can check. Still it is blank

Comment: What is your value in `$_POST['region_id']`? @skz. Check your console for that value is passed correctly or not!

Comment: value is not passing. i checked the console

Comment: No. Tried this new one

Answer (score 0):

in success call check if the result is empty then append results to id
When you change first clear the oldest of the state so that new values come in the place

```
<script>
$('#region').on('change', function(){
    $("#states-list").html(''); // empty the currnt values
        var region_id = this.value;
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "SearchRegion.php",
        data:'region_id='+region_id,
        success: function(result){
        $("#states-list").append(result); // then append new values
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hey I have tried this way. but it didn't work and you answer as well didn't work.